# c# WCF web service serialization error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, serialization

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm trying to create a WCF web service that access a different dll project.  The return is a custom list that contains strings and integars.  When debugging I get the following error when simply navigating to Service1.svc:

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description
>    contract: http://tempuri.org/:IService1 ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'RoTools.RoAmCalls+CustomItem' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types

So researching the error online I thought adding the KnownType would help, but I'm still getting the same error.  Thanks for your help.  Here is the code from the Service1.cs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace RoWebService
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem> SingleProductCheck(string productId); 
}


[KnownType(typeof(RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem))]
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{

    List<RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem> myResults;

    [DataMember]
    public List<RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem> myResults
    {
        get { return myResults; }
        set { myResults = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is the code from the Service1.svc.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace RoWebService
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem> SingleProductCheck(string productId)
    {
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


        var myReturn = 
        RoTools.RoAmCalls.GetPriceAndStatusSingleItem(productId, log, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something1"],
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something2"]);

        return myReturn;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: All user-defined types used in WCF (RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem in this case) must be marked with [DataContract] attribute. Its members must be marked with [DataMember] attribute. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have DataContract and DataMember marked. Did I do them incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't posted RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem implementation.

Comment: Maybe that's my mistake then.  All the code shown above is what I have right now.  I'm not sure how to go about what your stating though.

Comment: Do you have access to RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem source code?

Comment: Yes I do.  It returns 2 strings, 1 integar, and 1 bool as the return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144087/discussion-between-yevgeniy-and-roro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user-defined types used in WCF (`RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem` in this case) must be marked with `[DataContract]` attribute. Its members must be marked with `[DataMember]` attribute.

Mark `RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem` with `[DataContract]` attribute or consider create a separate class, that will store the data from `RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem` and will be passed through WCF.

Comment: To add to this for anyone that finds this in the future.  I actually had to go into the DLL class files and mark the original CustomItem, which was not in the WPF project, with [DataMember].  it was originally meant for a console application.  Adding [DataMember] to the class did not negatively affect the console application so I did not need to create a separate class.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: UPDATE : Although Yevgeniy's answer did stop my errors on the page after implementing this I actually found out that it did not return any data.  I instead had to switch the DLL reference from [DataMember] to [Serialized] to return the data I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace your Composite class to:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<RoTools.RoAmCalls.CustomItem> myResults { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So sorry, CustomItem class have not a DataContract attribute?